# How to click on the element using selenium where only "::Before" tag is present

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to Navigate on the next month in calendar using the Selenium with Java but for the `>` (Button on calendar to navigate in next month) element only below information is present.

```
<a class="react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--next">
::before
</a>==$0
```

and the class tag is not pointing to the `>` instead it is pointing somewhere else on the page only "::before" is pointing the element `>`

Please suggest how to click on `>` element ?

I tried with `Xpath //*[@class='react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--next']` but its points some where else on the page so this is not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--next']")).click();
```

[image: Please see this image for more information]

Comment: How many elements do you see when tried that xpath in browser dev tools element search?

Comment: only one element is displaying but not pointing to the ">" button

Comment: You can't select that with xpath, you would need to use getComputedStyle()

Comment: @vishalsaxena may be because same class name exists for the another date picker can you verify that the same class name does exists for any other elements ?

Comment: @pguardiario can you please explain me how?

Comment: @Dhru'soni yes this class name is unique for ">"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if WebDriver can retrieve pseudo element content for you. I think you would need to use Javascript. Below works, I tested.

**Open date picker**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='fl-input _9KqY' and @data-reactid='195']")).click();
```

**click on next elements or next month**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('a.react-datepicker__navigation--next',':before').click();");
```

Comment: I have one more question regarding the Javascript .. Actually I am learning selenium with Java so can you please suggest me where I can learn Javascript for selenium

Answer (score 0):

I am able to click on the next link using the css.

```
.react-datepicker__navigation--next
```

[image]

Comment: Yes Its also working can you please suggest how I can achieve the same using the Xpath?